# Regex Javascript except

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to match string with "adwords**" except adwordsPE

my input

```
adwordsPW 
adwordsPE 
adwordsWE
```

need to output

```
adwordsPW - true
adwordsPE - false
adwordsWE - true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
adwords(?!PE)[A-Z]{2}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zE0kJ9/1)